# Unable to copy data from CSV to MySQLdb using Python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I'm a total newbie to MySQL and Python and I'm trying to read a single column of float data from a simple csv file into a local MySQL table using python but it repeatedly throws me some error. After bashing my head at the keyboard for a few hours, I corrected a few syntactical mistakes and now I'm stuck here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also pardon my formatting of the question here as this is my first time.

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='',
    db='test1')
cursor = mydb.cursor()

csv_data = csv.reader(file('csv1.csv'))
for row in csv_data:

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO log1(speed) values( %s )" %row)
#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print "Done"
```

This is the error that is displayed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 13, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO log1(speed) values( %s )" %row)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 226, in execute

    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '['85.26'] )' at line 1")
```

The csv file contains certain test data as follows:

```
85.26
72.67
80.12
99.86
65.64
```

And my database appears to be of the following structure:

```
+-------+---------+
| speed | test_id |
+-------+---------+
| 98.86 |       1 |
| 88.86 |       2 |
| 78.86 |       3 |
+-------+---------+
```

Where **speed** is the field that needs to be read from the csv file and **test_id** is an auto-incrementing primary key

**EDIT**

As advised by Visweswaran, I have changed my code as follows:

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='',
    db='test1')
cursor = mydb.cursor()

csv_data = csv.reader(file('csv1.csv'))
for row in csv_data:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO log1(speed) values( %s )" %row[0])
#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print "Done"
```

Now this seems to have fixed the Type: List error but now I get the following error:

```
File "test2.py", line 12, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO log1(speed) values( %s )" %row[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic and doing something quite silly, but your support would be extremely helpful sir.

Comment: The error message you are getting is self explanatory, i.e you have an error in your query.

Comment: Thanks you sir for your quick response. And pardon me but I'm at a total loss here. Could you kindly point out what exactly the error is? As I said I'm entirely new to MySQL so I'd really need some help.

Comment: can you describe your table structure, like what is the type os speed and test_id

Comment: speed is supposed to be of float type , not null. test_id is supposed to be a unsigned int, not null, auto_increment, primary key

Comment: The query seems to be okay, but I think row is a list. use print type(row) to see whether it is a list or not.

Comment: You are correct. The type does show as a list. How should I proceed then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form your question I have reproduced a table like this,

> create table if not exists log1(speed float not null, test_id int(2) unsigned primary key auto_increment);

But the row is a list not string in the list, so I modified a bit your query into this,

```
>>> if len(row) > 0:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO log1(speed) values( %s )" %row[0])
```

The csv delivers the tuple(In database - which is also called a row) as a python list. since you have only one column I added row[0] which gives the value present in the first column for each row.

Finally, the value gets inserted

```
+-------+---------+
| speed | test_id |
+-------+---------+
| 85.26 |       1 |
| 72.67 |       2 |
| 80.12 |       3 |
```

**What Parfait is speaking:** why string formatting should not be used to construct query

He says that the code is vulnerable to Relational Database Management System Fingerprinting.

Consider this code in your table:

```
value = input("Enter the value: ")
cursor.execute("select * from log1 where test_id = "+value)
data = cursor.fetchall()
for i in data:
    print(i['speed'])
    print(i['test_id'])
```

In which an user is supposed to enter the value of the test_id and the speed and test_id gets displayed.

Consider, I am a remote user(attacker) Now I am inputting 1 and your program will output this

```
Enter the value: 1
1.0
1
Done
```

Ok, it is fine it gives me the speed and the test_id and the program is working fine.

Ok now I give this as an input as a crafted query,

```
Enter the value: 1 order by 1--
1.0
1
Done
```

See the same output displays but now when I give this query as an input Enter the value: 1 order by 3--
an error message is displayed so I who is living in remote place know that there is a table in your database which has two columns.

Now, see this input,

```
Enter the value: -1 union select 1,unhex(hex(version()))--
1.0
b'5.X.X-X'
Done
```

I can get your database version which is 5.X.X (The actual output will display the exact version. I am a bit paranoid).

This type of attack is called union based SQL Injection attack. There are various other categories like blind etc., I am not willing to induce so many things here.

So as he suggested, I would write a query to pass a parameter like this,

```
cursor.execute("select * from log1 where test_id = ",value)
```

Now we will try to get the version

```
Enter the value: 1 union select 1,unhex(hex(verison()))--
```

Result: TypeError....

Even this is not a complete solution. There are whole lot of vulnerabilities you must concentrate.

Please do not worry(as you said noobie) no body is expert in this security field. It takes experience.

Comment: Now this seems to have fixed the Type: List error but now I get the following error: 

File "test2.py", line 12, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO log1(speed) values( %s )" %row[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Then the row is empty, so why it is throwing the exception, It must be due to a plain line appended at the end of the text file. This can be solved using a conditional statement. See my update code in the answer

Comment: Of course you should be using [parameterized query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) and not string interpolation as some clever user can inject *Bobby Tables* in your csv file: `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO log1(speed) VALUES (%s)", row)`

Comment: @Parfait, I have updated my answer with RDBMS fingerprinting mechanisms and SQL injection(To my expertise) see if it is ok. Thank you for your kind response.